# How to import custom svg icons in vuetify 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

How to import custom svg icons in vuetify3 and nuxt3?

In vuetify 2, we were able to directly import svg icons like this

```
import customIcon from './myIcon.vue'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
    values: {
      myIcon: {component: customIcon}
    },
  },
})

---------------

// Used like this in vue file
<v-icon>$myIcon</v-icon>
```

From veutfiy 3 documentation, I am confused about importing custom svg icons as it is using sets instead of values.
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/

```
// plugins/vuetify.js
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";
import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/iconsets/mdi";
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    icons: {
      defaultSet: "mdi",
      aliases,
      sets: {
        mdi,
      },
    },
  });
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

Comment: welcome. 
Do you get any error in console or just wanna figure it out better?

Comment: Sort of yes. When I try to add custom icons then mdi icons don't work. I want to use both mdi and custom svg icons

Comment: Please post up yr error console

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a way to use both mdi and custom svg icons

Icon file

```
//tickicon.vue
<template>
<svg>... icon here</svg>
<template>
```

```
//customSvgs.ts
import { h } from "vue";
import type { IconSet, IconProps } from "vuetify";
import tickIcon from "./customSVGs/tickicon.vue";
import closeIcon from "./customSVGs/close-icon.vue";

const customSvgNameToComponent: any = {
  tickIcon,
  closeIcon,
};

const customSVGs: IconSet = {
  component: (props: IconProps) => h(customSvgNameToComponent[props.icon]),
};

export { customSVGs /* aliases */ };
```

And my vuetify plugin file

```
// plugins/vuetify.ts
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import { mdi } from "vuetify/iconsets/mdi";
import { customSVGs } from "~~/assets/customSVGs";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    icons: {
      defaultSet: "mdi",
      sets: {
        mdi,
        custom: customSVGs,
      },
    },
  });

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

Using like that in vue file

```
<v-icon icon="custom:tickIcon"/> //Custom SVG Icon 
<v-icon icon="mdi-arrow-up"/>  //default mdi icon
```

Answer (score 5):

Complement the answer of @rookie-coder

To get the correct vuetify v-icon style, you need to wrap the svg icon in a tag `<i>` and give the class `v-icon__svg` to the `<svg>` element.

```js
const custom: IconSet = {
  component: (props: IconProps) =>
    h(props.tag, [h(customSvgNameToComponent[props.icon as string], { class: 'v-icon__svg' })]),
}

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  icons: {
    defaultSet: "mdi",
    sets: {
      mdi,
      custom,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: to apply color to the icon remove all fill tags, to apply the size remove width and height of the svg

Answer (score 0):

Setup is same as my project, Did you include the actual icons at the top of `vuetify.js`?

`import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'`

Is the only thing I see missing from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vuetify 3 + Nuxt 3, and need to use a customized library such as nuxt-icon or iconify injected in v-icon, you can create a custom component to provide the inject with all heritage styles direct from v-icon.

1- Create a new component (in this exemple I'll use [nuxt-icon](https://nuxt.com/modules/icon):
*~/components/MyIcon.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Icon :name="name" :size="1em" />
    <!-- size as 1em will return the size of the inherited v-icon 
         as well as the color -->
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: "",
  },
});
</script>
```

2- Create a new render IconSet from Vuetify:
*~/components/MyIconRender.ts*

```js
import { h } from "vue";
import type { IconSet, IconProps } from "vuetify";
import MyIcon from "~~/components/MyIcon.vue";

const Icon: IconSet = {
  component: (props: IconProps) => {
    return h(MyIcon, {
      name: props.icon as string
    });
  },
};

export { MyIcon };
```

3- Configure Vuetify to use MyIcon as default:
*~/plugins/vuetify.ts*

```js
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";
import { MyIcon } from "~/components/MyIconRender";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    ssr: true,
    components,
    directives,
    icons: {
      defaultSet: "custom",
      sets: {
        custom: MyIcon,
      },
    },
  });
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
});
```

So in this way you can use any icon library injected direct in Vuetify 3. The best thing about this implementation is that all Vuetify 3 classes will work, for example: color: primary, or class pa-5, etc.